# Why does my HDMI display -sometimes- need to be manually reconnected after sleep?

Tags: display, sleep-wake, hdmi

My [27" Samsung display](https://www.engadget.com/2010/10/05/samsung-p2770fh-dips-down-to-1ms-response-time-costs-400/) stays connected to my 2015 MacBook Pro (MBP) at all times when I'm home via a standard HDMI cable. The display stays powered on. My MBP sometimes goes to sleep e.g., overnight.

*Sometimes*, but not every time, the display will fail to connect to the MBP when I wake up the laptop. The display is still on, but the MBP doesn't recognize it—i.e., it acts as if there's no display connected.

Unplugging and re-plugging the HDMI capable into the same MBP HDMI port reestablishes the connection.

I don't recall ever having the same problem with different monitors at work.

This question is [similar](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/85580/sleep-mode-problems-with-external-monitor) to [some](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/170893/dual-monitor-second-monitor-black-after-sleep-mode) [others](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/220986/dell-p2715q-needs-detect-displays-after-mbpr-15-goes-to-sleep), but no situation is quite the same.